# Deploy JS app to browser and nw.js or Atom Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nw.js

I want to know if there's a tool or way to develop a javascript application and have it deployed either to browser javascript or to a native application with nwjs or Atom Electron.
Of course it would have to use browser-compatible features and not native features of node.
I guess it's just a matter of how to bundle the files, but maybe there's a tool already to do that.

Comment: Since this is not the same environment I don't know if its possible to do that. But you have cool librairies like [browserify](http://browserify.org/). I'll tell you if I find more.

Comment: @RomainIsnel well, both have a DOM and basic javascript in common, so you can do a lot with the subset common to both.

Comment: You're right, but Electron also include a NodeJS environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [browserify](http://browserify.org/), it's really cool.

> browserify is a tool for compiling node-flavored commonjs modules for
>   the browser.
>
> You can use browserify to organize your code and use third-party
>   libraries even if you don't use node itself in any other capacity
>   except for bundling and installing packages with npm.
>
> The module system that browserify uses is the same as node, so
>   packages published to npm that were originally intended for use in
>   node but not browsers will work just fine in the browser too.
>
> Increasingly, people are publishing modules to npm which are
>   intentionally designed to work in both node and in the browser using
>   browserify and many packages on npm are intended for use in just the
>   browser. npm is for all javascript, front or backend alike

https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#introduction

Answer (score 0):

It is up to your development environment. 
I'm developing a Electron App which relies a bit on the ipc Messaging but If want to use this application also directly in the browser I would just create a wrapper around it and let the build tool handle these things (webpack, gulp, grunt...).

If you want to use Electron, you should look into the conventions the [Electron Builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder) wants. They separate the application and its dependencies from the development deps (electron, electron-builder etc).